# how to compare two strings using max function

Tags: php

guys how do make this two strings 00 & 00.00 be able to be compared using max(). they seem to be treated equally when i do

```
max($thearraythatcontaintsthem);
```

what i want to achieve is that when i do max(); 00.00 will be outputed.

how to do that? or any idea how to output 00.00 even if not using max() function

Comment: well.... they are equal.

Comment: what is your logic behind getting 00.00 as the result?

Comment: its for the threaded comment in drupal.

Comment: google a bit about the data types (or even in the php.net reference). Learn the difference between strings and Integers/floats

Answer (score 0):

Hik,

Try something like this:

```
$m0 = '00.00';
$maxnr = max('00', 0, '00.00');
if($maxnr > $m0) $m0 = $maxnr;
echo $m0;       // 00.00
```